# C++11 threads limit?

Tags: c++, multithreading

**edit 3:**  **WORKS** on win 7, **BSOD** on win 8.1. Thank's why I hate updates.

**edit 2:** I got a BSOD saying: "Attempted to write in read only memory: vtss.sys"

**edit**: There is a variable `WORD KEYS[1024];` being `read` but `only read`, never written by all threads. I am using visual studio 2012 on windows 8.1. Why does it crash?

Is there a limitation in the number of C++11 threads? I am trying to make 1k threads but **sometimes** the program crash at no 47... Why 47?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

WORD KEYS[1024];

void thread_job(int no)
{
    cout << KEYS[0] << KEYS[no] << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int items = 1000;

    std::thread *tt = new std::thread[items];

    for(int i = 0; i < items; i++)
    {
        tt[i] = thread(thread_job, i+1);
        cout << i << endl;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < items; i++)
        tt[i].join();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you want to use multiple threads...It better to go for thread pool.

Comment: be glat its not a crash at 42

Comment: C++11 doesn't specify this. It is down to your platform and OS.

Comment: can someone explain why this crashes?

Comment: @Blazer As was mentioned in the other comments, the thread limit is up to your OS. Maybe it's a bug. Try to repeat it on other systems and see what happens. Maybe it's a bug in the C++11 implementation that you are using. Try using a different tool chain to verify that.

Comment: @Blazer: Well, I can't say for sure, because I don't know what jobs the threads are executing. Post a simple, concise, and **complete** example.

Comment: Why are you creating so many threads? this will degrade the performance of your program

Comment: There are many reasons why the code could crash. You didn't even show the definition of `thread_job` to see what's going on. Most likely there is some data race.

Comment: I am just testing the threads, I am not using so many in a program. I am trying to understand how they work and why they crash at random.

Comment: @Blazer: Then post *all of your code*. And compiler info. -1 until you do, because otherwise all we can do is guess.

Comment: @Blazer: Almost. Add your `#include`s and **everything else** (including the `using namespace std;` you omitted). Then I'll remove my -1. I know I'm being picky, but I can't stress the importance of a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable) Example](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: If your user code manages to generate a kernel fault you either found a really serious bug in the kernel (possible but unlikely) or something screwed up your OS installation (malware, broken drivers,..). A write into ROM could certainly be faulty malware.

Comment: The crash in vtss.sys is likely to be a bug in the Intel VTune driver.

Answer (score 4):

Without knowing *anything* about your code, which OS you're targeting or which compiler you're using, I am willing to say that *you can have more than 47 threads*. What you are seeing is a bug in *your* code, not the compiler, OS or language conspiring against you.

However, there is virtually no sane reason to do what you are doing. You don't *want* 1000 threads, but you can create them just fine.

If you want help in determining why your code crashes, post a full code sample that reproduces the problem.

Comment: To add to this (true statement) "You don't want 1000 threads": executing multiple threads requires [context switching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch), and while it's a small price to pay for a few threads, it adds up when you've got a lot of threads (like 1000). 1000 threads will actually *slow you down*.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use multiple threads it is better to go for a thread pool.

[Howto](http://progsch.net/wordpress/?p=81)